# Не добавляются данные с формы HTML в бд PhpMyAdmin. (OpenServer)

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, mysqli

Не получается добавить данные в таблицу из формы.
Браузер пишет, что все прошло успешно, однако, в таблицу никаких данных не приходит (она не заполняется).

Код HTML :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Преподаватели </title>
    <style>
    tb {
    opacity: .5;
    }
    </style>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body style="background-image:url(ships.gif); font-size:20pt; background-size: 100%"> <center>


    <form name="f1" action="Vvod_2.php" method="post">
    <table border="4" cellspacing="9" cellpadding="10" style="background-image:url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/48/e8/62/48e8623f3f6f3da7e932ade8d6e2b0bd.png); font-size:15pt; color: white">
        <caption> Преподаватели </caption>
        <TBODY>
        <tr align="center">
            <td><label for=number>Таб_преп</label></td>
            <td><input name=number></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <td><label for=name> Фамилия: </label></td>
            <td><input name=Fam></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <td><label for=name> Имя: </label></td>
            <td><input name=imya></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <td><label for=name> Отечество: </label></td>
            <td><input name=otch></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <td><label for=pol> Пол </label></td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="pol" value="Женский">Женский<br>
                <input type="radio" name="pol" value="Мужской">Мужской
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <td><label for=data> Дата рождения </label></td>
            <td><input name=data></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input name="btn1" value="ВВЕСТИ ДАННЫЕ" type="submit">
    <input name="btn2" value="ОБНОВИТЬ ДАННЫЕ" type="submit">
    <input name="btn3" value="УДАЛИТЬ ДАННЫЕ" type="submit">
        <input  name="btn4" value="ОЧИСТИТЬ" type="reset">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Код PHP :

```
<?php
    
    if (isset($_POST['btn1']) || isset($_POST['btn2'])) 

    {
        
    $qu = "REPLACE prepodavateli SET tab_prep = '".$_POST['number']."',
    fam_prep = '".$_POST['Fam']."',
    name_prep = '".$_POST['imya']."',
    otch_prep = '".$_POST['otch']."',
    pol = '".$_POST['pol']."',
    data_roj = '".$_POST['data']."'";
        echo $qu;

    }

    elseif(isset($_POST['btn3'])) 
    {   
    $qu = "DELETE from prepadovateli

    where number = '".$_POST['number']."'";
    echo "Запрос выполнен успешно!";
    }

    $c = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
    mysqli_select_db($c,'uch_proc');
    mysqli_query($c,'SET NAMES cp1251');
    mysqli_query($c,$qu);

?>
```

БД :

[image: БД на PhpMyAdmin]

Comment: естественно, ты же выводишь сообщение об успешности запроса к БД до его выполнения))

Comment: выкинь эту книгу и скачай лет на 10-15 книгу посвежее

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо !